# 'ActionRow' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send a message with buttons, but it gives an error

Before that, the code was in one file and worked, but as soon as I wanted to move everything to cog, this error came out

```
  File "/home/bot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1353, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/home/bot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 209, in invoke
    return await self.func(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bot/cogs/controlpanel.py", line 68, in clear
    await ctx.send(embed=emb, components=[row])
  File "/home/bot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/context.py", line 215, in send
    if components and not all(comp.get("type") == 1 for comp in components):
  File "/home/bot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/context.py", line 215, in <genexpr>
    if components and not all(comp.get("type") == 1 for comp in components):
AttributeError: 'ActionRow' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My code:

```py
class Controlpanel(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, bot):
       self.bot = bot

   @cog_ext.cog_slash(name='controlpanel', description='Разместить панель управления сервером',
                guild_ids=[928666080929542194])
   @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
   async def clear(self, ctx: SlashContext):
       emb = discord.Embed(
           description =
           f"""
           Панель управления сервером через дискорд
           """,
           colour = 0xffba42
       )
       emb.set_author(name='Панель управления')

       row = ActionRow(
           Button(
               style=ButtonStyle.grey,
               label='Статус',
               custom_id='status'
           ),
           Button(
               style=ButtonStyle.green,
               label='Запуск',
               custom_id='on'
           ),
           Button(
               style=ButtonStyle.red,
               label='Выключить',
               custom_id='off'
           ),
           Button(
               style=ButtonStyle.green,
               label='Перезапуск',
               custom_id='restart'
           ),
           Button(
               style=ButtonStyle.red,
               label='Убить',
               custom_id='kill'
           )
       )
       await ctx.send(embed=emb, components=[row])

   @commands.Cog.listener()
   async def on_button_click(self, inter):
       if inter.component.id == "status":
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
           command = "pzserver status"
           stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
           lines = stdout.readlines()
           str1 = ''.join(lines)
           print(time() + ' - ' + str1)
           ssh.close()
           await inter.reply(str1, ephemeral = True)
       if inter.component.id == "on":
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
           command = "pzserver start"
           ssh.exec_command(command)
           ssh.close()
           await inter.reply('Запускаю сервер! ', ephemeral = True)
       if inter.component.id == "off":
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
           command = "pzserver stop"
           ssh.exec_command(command)
           ssh.close()
           await inter.reply('Выключаю сервер! ', ephemeral = True)
       if inter.component.id == "kill":
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
           command = "pzserver kill"
           stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
           lines = stdout.readlines()
           str1 = ''.join(lines)
           print(time() + ' - ' + str1)
           ssh.close()
           await inter.reply(str1, ephemeral = True)
       if inter.component.id == "restart":
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
           command = "pzserver restart"
           ssh.exec_command(command)
           ssh.close()
           await inter.reply('Перезапускаю сервер! ', ephemeral = True)
           my_channel = self.bot.get_channel(936698972561637496)
           emb = discord.Embed(
               description =
               f"""
               Сервер перезапуститься через 15 минут.
               """,
               colour = 0xffba42
           )
           emb.set_author(name = 'Перезапуск сервера!')
           await my_channel.send(embed = emb)

def setup(bot):
   bot.add_cog(Controlpanel(bot))
```

Comment: from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext
from dislash import ActionRow, Button, ButtonStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from discord_slash.utils.manage_components import create_actionrow, create_button

@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='controlpanel', description='Разместить панель управления сервером',
             guild_ids=[928666080929542194])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(self, ctx: SlashContext):
    emb = discord.Embed(
        description =
        f"""
        Панель управления сервером через дискорд
        """,
        colour = 0xffba42
    )
    emb.set_author(name='Панель управления')

    row = create_actionrow(*[
        create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.grey,
            label='Статус',
            custom_id='status'
        ),
        create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.green,
            label='Запуск',
            custom_id='on'
        ),
        create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.red,
            label='Выключить',
            custom_id='off'
        ),
        create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.green,
            label='Перезапуск',
            custom_id='restart'
        ),
        create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.red,
            label='Убить',
            custom_id='kill'
        )
    ])
    await ctx.send(embed=emb, components=[row])
```

`components` should be delivered in the form of a dict.

- If you use `interaction.py 4.0.0~`, you can use `from interactions.models.component import ActionRow` [module github](https://github.com/interactions-py/library/blob/eeafc565a90facd7c755d6122079ee1473259fc0/interactions/models/component.py#L309)